# mysql sum each row

Tags: mysql, sum, row

query to get the results as below

table price(
item int,
amount int,
quantity int,
)

```
+-------+-------+----------+
| item  | price | quantity |
+-------+-------+----------+
| box 1 |  1000 |        4 |
| box 2 |  2000 |        1 |
| box 3 |  3000 |        6 |
+-------+-------+----------+
```

---

result

```
+-------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+
| item  | price | quantity | sub total | total |
+-------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+
| box 1 |  1000 |        4 |      4000 | 16000 |
| box 2 |  2000 |        1 |      2000 | 18000 |
| box 3 |  3000 |        6 |     18000 | 36000 |
+-------+-------+----------+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: please apply formatting. What have you tried? What results do you want?

Comment: what is your mysql version?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try below if your mysql version below 8.0

```
select 
    item,price,quantity,price*quantity as total, 
    @totalall:= @totalall + price*quantity as TotalAll
from price, (Select @totalall:= 0) as totalall;
```

OR if your mysql vsersion 8.0+ then you can try below -

```
SELECT 
    item,price,quantity,price*quantity as total, 
    SUM(price*quantity) OVER(ORDER BY item) AS TotalAll
FROM price;
```

Answer (score -1):

Select item, amount, (@sum:=@sum+(item*amount)) as Quantity from  cross join (select @sum:=0) params